# I'm trying to add an h2 containing the input text to the to the div with class "the-div"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

```
<html>
<body>
    <form class="form-disable">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="message2">
        <br>
         <button id="myButton" type="submit" disabled>Generate Text</button> 
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="jQueryDrills.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
       
$("#message2").blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() =='') {
        $("#myButton").prop( "disabled", true );
    } else {
        $("#myButton").prop( "disabled", false );
    }
})

// function text(){
//     let $box = $('#message2').val();
//     alert($box);
// }

$(".form-disable").after("<div class='the-div' style='background-color: red;'>Im Dumb</div>");

$("#myButton").click(function(event){
let theH2 = document.createElement('h2');
let $alert = $('#message2').val();
$(theH2).append('$alert');
$("the-div").append(theH2);
event.preventDefault();
})

$("#message2").click(function(){
    $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    // event.preventDefault();
})

$(".buttn").click(function(event){

    $('body').append('<div>Hello</div>');
    event.preventDefault();
})

$(".buttn2").click(function(){
    $('body').removeAll();
})
</script>
```

I am trying to add an `h2` element to the `div` with the class `the-div` with value from the input field after the user clicks 'Generate Text'.

I've tested the function that is supposed to be entering the h2 into the div with a console log and it works. So I'm pretty sure my issue has to do with appending, but I cant see why. Also please ignore the commented-out function that was another test that did actually work as well, furthering me to believe it is an appending error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not selecting the `div` properly. You were missing the `.` for selecting elements with a class
2. Why are you appending text to an `h2` element? Use `.text(yourtext)` instead.

```js
$("#message2").blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $("#myButton").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#myButton").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
$(".form-disable").after("<div class='the-div' style='background-color: red;'>Im Dumb</div>");

$("#myButton").click(function(event) {
  let theH2 = document.createElement('h2');
  let $alert = $('#message2').val();
  $(theH2).text($alert);
  $(".the-div").append(theH2);
  event.preventDefault();
})

$("#message2").click(function() {
  $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
  // event.preventDefault();
})

$(".buttn").click(function(event) {

  $('body').append('<div>Hello</div>');
  event.preventDefault();
})

$(".buttn2").click(function() {
  $('body').removeAll();
})
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form class="form-disable">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="message2">
    <br>
    <button id="myButton" type="submit" disabled>Generate Text</button>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="jQueryDrills.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That period missing is embarrassing. That text function is very useful tho, thank you! Should I take this post down since it was a dumb mistake?

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a lot of code for something easy.

Better use this; there is no need for jQuery or anything else.

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let oldText = document.getElementById("the-div").innerHTML;
  let inputText = document.getElementById("message2").value;
  document.getElementById("the-div").innerHTML = oldText + '<h2>' + inputText + '</h2>';
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="message2">
    <button id="myButton">Generate Text</button>
</body>
</html>
<div id='the-div' style='background-color: red;'>Im Dumb</div>
```